# How can I display the list of all users using react-redux?

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to display the list of users but I'm not getting where I'm going wrong. Can someone please help me? How can I display the list of users.
I've appended the response that I'm getting from the backend.

Here's the code :

### UsersList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {listAllUsers} from '../../actions'

class ListUsers extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.listAllUsers()
    }
    usersList(){
        return this.props.users.map((user)=>{
            return (
                <div key={user.id}>
                    <div>{user.fullname}</div>
                    <div>{user.address}</div>
                    <div>
                        <button>Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button>Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Users List</h1>
                {this.usersList()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
    console.log(state)
    return {users:state.users}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{listAllUsers:listAllUsers})(ListUsers)
```

---

### actions.js

```
import {ADD_USER,USERS_LIST} from '../actions/types'
import users from '../apis/users'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

export const listAllUsers=()=>{
    return async (dispatch)=>{
        const response=await users.get('/users')
        dispatch({
            type:USERS_LIST,
            payload:response.data
        })
    }
}
```

---

### userReducer.js

```
    import {USERS_LIST} from '../actions/types'
    
    const userReducer=(state=[],action)=>{
        switch(action.type){
            case USERS_LIST:
                return [...state,action.payload]
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
    export default userReducer
```

---

Comment: If your payload is an array you are adding an array inside another array at reducer. Maybe you wanted to do like`[...state, ...action.payload]`?

Comment: What output you are actually getting? Any error or no output at all?